# Programmatically setting a counter to a substring

Tags: tex-core, errors, counters, strings

I'm trying to set a counter based on the name of the current job. I've got the number I need by doing something like `\substring{\jobname}{5}{5}}` using the `stringstrings` package, and if I just output that into the document, I see the right value. However, naively trying to use it as an argument to `\setcounter` fails with the error "Missing number, treated as zero." I don't know enough about TeX internals to speculate intelligently on what's going on here, so I'll simply ask: How should I make this work?

Minimal example (save this as `file3-example.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\begin{document}
% \substring{\jobname}{5}{5} % this outputs 3
\setcounter{section}{\substring{\jobname}{5}{5}} % this fails
\section{Foo}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already stated the `\setcounter{section}{..}` must only include material which expands to a number. The string manipulation macro requires assignments internally, I guess, which makes it not fully expandable, so it causes an error.

I would recommend the `xstring` package instead. Its macros can also store the returned string into a (then expandable!) macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
\StrChar{\jobname}{5}[\mysubstring]%
% Or: (useful if the number would be two digits long
%\StrMid{\jobname}{5}{5}[\mysubstring]%
\setcounter{section}{\mysubstring}%
\addtocounter{section}{-1}% because it is incremented in \section
\section{Foo}
\end{document}
```

Note the egreg's answer is very fine and does not require a most likely big package to be loaded. I just wanted to show a LaTeX-highlevel solution for people which prefer that.

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution I ended up using -- it "feels nicer" to be able to use a substring macro.

Answer (score 7):

This can't work, because the argument of `\setcounter` must be, after expansion, a number, while `\substring` has to perform many calculations which require commands incompatible with the syntax of `\setcounter`.

To access the fifth character of `\jobname` you can do in an indirect way:

```
\def\extractfifth#1#2#3#4#5#6\relax{#5}

\setcounter{section}{\expandafter\extractfifth\jobname\relax}
\addtocounter{section}{-1}
```

The first line should go in the preamble. However in this way the section would be number 4, since it's `\section` that increments the counter. That's the purpose of the following `\addtocounter`.

Answer (score 6):

stringstrings works just fine.  The key is to use substring in `[q]` quiet mode, so that the result is saved in the variable `\thestring`.  Then, `\thestring` can be passed to setcounter

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\begin{document}
\jobname
\substring[q]{\jobname}{5}{5} % this outputs 3
\setcounter{section}{\thestring}
\section{Foo}
\end{document}
```

The key to stringstrings usefulness is the ability to produce results as simple (able to edef) strings, rather than as tokens.